# Lossless video codec squashing dim pixels using avconv

Tags: video, video-processing, libav, avconv

I am using avconv to convert a raw avi grayscale video to huffyuv with mkv container. I've read that huffyuv is "mathematically lossless", which is precisely what I want. avoprobe on the input file gives

```
Input #0, avi, from 'myvid.avi':   Duration: 00:00:32.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129167 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, pal8, 328x246, 200 fps, 0.08 tbr, 200 tbn, 200 tbc
```

The movie has high intensity (approx 150-250 in 8 bits) and low intensity (1-9) elements that I would like to preserve. However if I run

```
avconv -y -an -i myvid.avi -r 200 -c:v huffyuv av_test.mkv
```

I get a text.mkv where the low intensity details have vanished. In fact I was able to plot the following for the two videos.
[image: Squashing of dim pixels]

So avconv is deciding I don't need those critical dim pixels. I could just add, say, 15 to all pixel values, but then I would saturate my bright pixels and there's no guarantee the cutoff value is the same for all videos. I do some downstream processing on the output where I really need pixel values to not change when I convert video formats. Any insights as to how to get avconv or huffyuv to actually save my video without loss?

EDIT: I've discovered that there is clipping of both the bright and dim pixels. Also, the issue seems to be coming from the conversion of the gray pixel format to anything else, since I see the issue with other lossless codecs like ffv1 and lossless H264.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought but are you sure this is not a difference in interpretation of black levels? (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_level)

Comment: Thank you! It does appear to be a blacklevel/whitelevel issue (I noticed that it also clips on the high end as well). The Wikipedia article mentioned that this arises when converting computer output to standard video format. Now how can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Don't know, but glad I could help.